# Log Normal distribution function for calculating Cumulative Weight Fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code for generating the cumulative weight fraction. However, the results are slightly different from those that I desire (see the table below - Desired Results). Can anyone help?

The inputs are D50 = 1 and Geometric Mean Deviation = 0.4

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm

def lognormal_cdf(x, D50, gsd):
    # Calculate parameters mu and sigma of the lognormal distribution
    sigma = np.sqrt(np.log(1 + (gsd ** 2)))
    mu = np.log(D50) - 0.5 * sigma ** 2
    
    # Calculate and return the CDF value
    cdf = lognorm.cdf(x, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
    return cdf

D50 = 1.0  # Median value (D50)
gsd = 0.4   # Geometric standard deviation

# Example usage
lower_limit = 0.0
upper_limit = 10.0
intervals = 10  # Value for which CDF needs to be calculated
diff = (upper_limit - lower_limit) / intervals

lower_limits = np.linspace(lower_limit, upper_limit - diff, intervals)
upper_limits = np.linspace(lower_limit + diff, upper_limit, intervals)

# Calculate the CDF
cdf_value = lognormal_cdf(upper_limits, D50, gsd)

# Print the CDF value
df = pd.DataFrame([lower_limits, upper_limits, cdf_value]).T
df.columns = ['lower limits', 'upper limits', 'cumulative mass fraction']
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Desired Results**

[image: desired results]

I have tried to solve the problem by using lognorm.cdf(x, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu)) and by making transformation found on the internet.

Comment: where do the results that "you desire" come from ?

Comment: From aspen plus. I also made some modifications to the code provided because the previous version had some issues.